# gitlab CI create docker image and push to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab-ci

I setup a docker registry (ECR) on AWS. From my gitlab repository I'd like to setup a CI to automatically create images and push them to the repository. 
I was following the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/@stijnbe/using-gitlab-ci-with-aws-container-registry-ecaf4a37d791) to setup everything, but when running the example, I receive the error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

My yml file looks like this

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  REPOSITORY_URL: <aws-url>/<registry>/outsite-slackbot

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
  - pip install awscli

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)
```

Comment: Are you using a private runner or one from gitlab.com?

Comment: I'm using shared runners, so no private ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the Dockerfile, you can't be connected to docker daemon by the way. So check these steps:

- Are you logged in as a root? (`sudo su` or `sudo -i`)
- Start Docker service (`service docker start`)

Then follow the tutorial :)

Comment: Can I start the service from within the CI?

Comment: You should start it from your Gitlab server then your Gitlab-CI will request to Docker.

Comment: What do you mean start it from the github server? Shouldn't the docker daemon run inside the defined image (in this case docker:latest which is alpine)?

Comment: You can't run docker daemon inside the image, you just can use it, You want to use a docker image inside your Gitlab-CI config (the yml file) but the problem is your connection to docker, And without Docker there is no Docker image. So You need at least one Gitlab-runner for your CI inside the Gitlab server. By default there is not Gitlab-runner installed on Gitlab.

* [Install Docker runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)